# Facebook API: is it possible to get a user's public profile data by email address?

Tags: facebook, email, email-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find Facebook user (url to profile page) by known email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234651/find-facebook-user-url-to-profile-page-by-known-email-address)

I have a list of email addresses from people that use my app. Is it possible to query for their facebook public data by email address?

Thanks Richard.

Answer (score 26):

Any application can fetch users(application authorized users) facebookID in user basic information via graph api or fql.
for exa.
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=[facebook returned access token]

it will return these information in JSON

```
{
   "id": "100001114785800",
   "name": "Stella Jackson",
   "first_name": "Stella",
   "last_name": "Jackson",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100001114785800",
   "birthday": "04/16/1987",
   "gender": "female",
   "interested_in": [
      "female"
   ],
   "timezone": 5.5,
   "locale": "en_US",
   "updated_time": "2010-10-08T13:26:10+0000"
}
```

Once you get user ID you can fetch user picture via graph api

https://graph.facebook.com/[user facebook id]?fields=id,name,picture
https://graph.facebook.com/100001114785800?fields=id,name,picture

OR

https://graph.facebook.com/100001114785800/picture?type=small

type can be small, normal, large, square

Best luck Richard

Comment: How to get email id using the same

Answer (score 0):

Facebook use the facebook id to access user information via api or via FQL instead of email id.

Comment: problem is that you can't get the users' ID. Any app will have a user name and firstname, and also email address, but you won't be able to get a users' picture that way