# Get user photo with known email address from within iOS app

Tags: facebook, image, email, facebook-graph-api, search

I want to automatically download user's profile photo from Facebook from within iOS app when an email is provided. I'm doing it by performing search to get user id.

The app will be used by many people, so there shouldn't be logged user, eventually app should authenticate itself.

My problem is getting `access_token` to do that. Similar solution is implemented in the Sparrow (email client for OSX and iOS).

My guess was to acquire an `access_token` by making request with this url:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&grant_type=search", appId, appSecret];
```

but in return i'm getting this:

```
{"error":{"message":"Missing redirect_uri parameter.","type":"OAuthException","code":191}}
```

anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need a user access token to be able to search by email address; see [Find Facebook user (url to profile page) by known email address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5234651/441108).