# How to find facebook account with emailid by using api

Tags: facebook, twitter

I am developing an application, in my application there is a requirement , to find the users profile based on EmailID in facebook and twitter using api's.
I have tried a lot but did not found any results
but when i using third party licensed api's they were getting the data from various social networking sites using emailid as input

Can any one please suggest me how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has removed the ability to search by email this year. It is covered in this [stack overflow thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234651/find-facebook-user-url-to-profile-page-by-known-email-address)
Even using FQL, it is neccessary for your app to have been approved by a user before it is able to access a user email. In the case where they have opted in all that is required is

```
  SELECT email FROM user WHERE uid=FRIEND_ID
```

in the facebook FQL console.

Twitter has a similar rule for their API, and trying to search for *user@email.com* will end up looking for a user *@email.com*.

You will need to find other methods to search for users; searching by email tends to only be open in the app that the API creators made, and not for general public use.