# perform facebook user search without login php sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to build an application where user will enter some email id and we will provide him facebook info of the account associated with that email.I have tried it using php sdk but it said that user access token was required. We don't want to let user login for performing search.If anybody can help me please give your appreciated time.I have also gone through the post :

[[Find Facebook user (url to profile page) by known email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234651/find-facebook-user-url-to-profile-page-by-known-email-address][1])

but no luck with that too.

Comment: Have you tried with an application access token? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens Can you include some of the code you have tried in your question?

Comment: yes I did but still its shows me that a user token is required.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for any user information via the Graph API requires an `access_token`. You can only search for `posts` and other objects without an `access_token`. This is mainly to respect users' privacy settings around blocked users, search restrictions etc.

Furthermore, you definitely won't be able to search by email address, even with an `access_token`:

> The ability to pass in an e-mail address into the "user" search type
>   was removed on July 10, 2013. This search type only returns results
>   that match a user's name (including alternate name).

Comment: can you please let me know if there is any other option to find the users by email id?